# Should I reset my iPhone before getting my cracked screen fixed at the Genius Bar?

Tags: apple-store

In an hour I am going to the Apple Store and get my cracked screen replaced or fixed. Since I still have time, should I restore my phone to factory settings first? I have already backed it up on my computer.

Comment: I wouldn't. If you're concerned about privacy, make sure it has a passcode, but I wouldn't worry about it beyond that.

Comment: I have a passcode and the employee asked me for the passcode "just in case something goes wrong" and then I reset the phone.